# Java, how to get reference of an object

Tags: java, class, oop

Let's say I have 3 classes; A , B and C. Class A and B are in one package. C is in another package. B is having a public function that returns a boolean value.

Object of B is created in Class A and he can call the functions of Class B. But the problem is that in Class C I want to have the reference of Class B object created by Class A, I don't want to create one more Class B object in Class C.How can I get that.

Example: Class B and Class A are in same package

*B.java*

```
class B
{
     public boolean fun()
     {
          returns boolValue;
     }
}
```

*A.java*

```
class A
{
     B b = new B(); //Creates object of Class B and can access function.
}
```

Class C is in another package and different project also.

*C.java*

```
class C
{
     //How to get the reference of Class B object created in Class A?
}
```

Once I get the reference to that I am going to call the functions of Class B to get the values. I tried writing some get() which returns the object of class B but to call that function I should have the object. But I don't know how to do that. This might be easy but I am new to java and I don't know how to do that. Please do help me to solve this problem.

**UPDATE : I can't create Class A object in Class C :( **

Comment: Make a `public B getB()` method in class `A` which will return `b`.

Comment: *"B is having a public function that returns a boolean value"* Wrong, `fun()` is not public (*method* is more correct in Java parlance), it is package-private.

Comment: @kayaman: But how to call `getB()` I don't have reference of Class A object. :(

Comment: @Thushi It depends. You can create an `A` in your `C` class, if it makes sense. It's hard to say what's correct, since you used the non-descriptive names `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: you have written as "Class C is in another package and different project also" is it true ? if c is in different project than you can not access it with any way...

Comment: @Keval: Why is it like that? I added it in my dependency of Class C project.

Comment: @thushi how you have added that as dependency, have you added a jar ?

Comment: @Keval: No I added it to the build path

Answer (score 0):

Make class A public

```
publi class A {

        private static B b = new B(); //Creates object of Class B and can access function.

        public static B getB() {
            return b;
          }
        }

          class C
          {
               //I want to get the reference of Class B object created in Class A....But How??? :(
          B b = A.getB(); //if it works ????
          }
```

Comment: I don't want to create the Class A object also :(

Comment: @Thushi, then static function will help ? Edited.

Comment: Class B needs to be public as well or you can't import it in C.

Comment: @AndroidKiller: I am doing some operations on Class A constructor. So, If I create it the constructor will be called again.

Comment: Also b is specified as instance field in OP code, not static. If you make it static, you should explain what this implies.

Comment: What is the static function approach.. Please do help me with that.

Comment: @Thushi, static variable and function are all class level which can be accessed with class name directly without any instance. If you are creating any instances of the class, then all instances will share one common copy of static variable.

Comment: @AndroidKiller: Then is it ok to make only getB() function as static? I don't want to make the object `b` as static.Will it work?

Comment: @Thushi, as you have mentioned here problem, for that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Classes `A` and `B` need to be public and class `A` needs to provide a public accessor to the required field.

```
public class B {
}

public class A {
    public B getB() {
        return this.b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your current code structure you will not be able to automatically instantiate B from your A object outside of a method.

You can create an A object in the class description but to initialize B you'll need to use the class constructor.

```
public class A {
    private B b = new B();
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

public class C {
    private A a = new A();
    private B b;
    public C() {
        b = a.getB();
    }
}
```

or, if you don't want to create A, you may make it `static`.

```
public static class A {
    private static B b = new B();
    public static B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

public class C {
    private B b;
    public C() {
        b = A.getB();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am using the static approach. Is that necessary to make the object B also static?. Can I make only getB() as static? Will it work?

Comment: If you make only `A.getB()` static it will not work. `b` element in `A` may also be static so that the method can access and return the variable without instantiating an `A` element. On the other hand `B` class doesn't need to be static as the element will be instantiated in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get access in C to A class and then share B reference by field.

So you may do something like this:

```java
 class B { //your function... }
 class A { 
     B b = new B();

     public B getB() { return b }
 }
 class C {
     A a = new A();
     public B getB () { return a.getB() }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to class C with object b as parameter

```
public class C{
    private B bObj;
    public C(B b){
        bObj=b;
    }
}
```

call this constructor from within your A class, which will create a reference to the created B object and you'll have this ref in `bObj`.